# Access Oracle database remotely installed on Google cloud VPS

Tags: oracle11g, vps

I have oracle database 11g installed on google cloud VPS which I need to access remotely. However, when I try to connect it via sql developer it throws following error. I ping the vps server IP that works. Please help me fix this issue.

connection info given: hostname=[vps IP] Port=1521 Service_name=dbnname

ERROR
Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: The most likely explanation is that communication on port 1521 is not open. There is either a routing rule or a firewall policy in place (probably by default) that is blocking the connection.

Comment: Port is enabled. I'm able to connect to this port on the server machine via sql developer. Also, turned off the firewall. Still same error.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is fixed. Entry(IP and machine name) in the host file is must in client computer to access the database hosted on the remote server.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.